# Basic Python plotting

Tags: python, geopandas, heat-map, fiona, matplotlib-basemap

Sorry if I sound like I don't understand, but I've been reading around trying to figure out how to do geospatial plotting in Python. I keep running into errors despite the examples I've seen appearing rather within reach.

Currently I have some San Francisco data, where each row is an observation that also contains long/lat data. I would like to do a heatmap of the frequency of the observations. I've come across people using various packages, and I believe some things that are required are shapefiles.

However, for some reason I can't seem to decipher the precise order from which I do things. Does it work like so:

1. Find a shapefile for San Francisco (with neighborhood polygons)
2. Plot the shapefile
3. Overlay a heatmap of the long/lat data

Is this correct? I'm looking for some guidance for a simple way where I can do this using Python 3.x. I've tried packages like Fiona, basemap, GeoPandas, etc., but I'm getting frustrated by not being able to find a simple solution that works in my notebook.

Comment: You can plot using geopandas and matplotlib. Post your code attempt and you will get help.